# Оставить hover у ссылки по которой открыли под-меню

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Есть меню, в нем ссылки. И если при навести курсор на ссылку - появляется подменю еще.

Вопрос: Каким образом оставлять выделенной ссылку, в под-меню которой сейчас находится курсор?

```css
.navig {
 width: 300px;
 font-family: 'Arsenal';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #f5f9f2;
}

.navig .links .no-sub {
 color: #000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
 list-style: none;
}

.navig .links .no-sub:last-child {
 border-bottom: 0px;
}

.navig .links .no-sub a {
 display: block;
 padding: 14px;
 color: #000;
 border-left: 1px solid #f5f9f2;
}

.navig .links .no-sub a:hover {
 display: block;
 padding: 14px;
 color: #000;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-left: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

.navig .links .no-sub:last-child a:hover {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

.navig .links .no-sub:first-child a:hover {
 border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

.navig .links .no-sub:last-child a {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.navig .links .no-sub:first-child a {
 border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}


.sub-menu {
 margin-left: 299px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -47px;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 0;
 width: 270px;
 z-index: 99999;
 border-right: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
 /*border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;*/
 border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
 display: none;
}


.sub-menu .sub {
 list-style: none;
}

.sub-menu .sub a {
 display: block;
}

.sub-menu .sub a:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.sub-menu .sub:first-child a:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
 text-decoration: underline;
 border-top: 0px solid #000;
}


.links > .no-sub:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navig">
    <div class="links">
        <li class="no-sub">
            <a href="/">Первая категория</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="sub"><a href="/">1Первая ссылка</a></li>
                    <li class="sub"><a href="/">1Вторая ссылка</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="no-sub">
            <a href="/">Вторая категория</a>
        </li>
        <li class="no-sub">
            <a href="/">Категория с подкатегориями</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="sub"><a href="/">Первая ссылка</a></li>
                    <li class="sub"><a href="/">Вторая ссылка</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="no-sub">
            <a href="/">Вторая категория</a>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как вариант, использовать не .navig .links .no-sub a:hover, а .navig .links .no-sub:hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.navig .links .no-sub:hover a{
  код
}
```

Пример

```css
.navig {
 width: 300px;
 font-family: 'Arsenal';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #f5f9f2;
}

.navig .links .no-sub {
 color: #000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
 list-style: none;
}

.navig .links .no-sub:last-child {
 border-bottom: 0px;
}

.navig .links .no-sub a {
 display: block;
 padding: 14px;
 color: #000;
 border-left: 1px solid #f5f9f2;
}
.navig .links .no-sub:hover a,
.navig .links .no-sub a:hover {
 display: block;
 padding: 14px;
 color: #000;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-left: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

.navig .links .no-sub:last-child a:hover {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

.navig .links .no-sub:first-child a:hover {
 border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

.navig .links .no-sub:last-child a {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.navig .links .no-sub:first-child a {
 border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}


.sub-menu {
 margin-left: 299px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -47px;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 0;
 width: 270px;
 z-index: 99999;
 border-right: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
 /*border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;*/
 border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
 display: none;
}


.sub-menu .sub {
 list-style: none;
}

.sub-menu .sub a {
 display: block;
}

.sub-menu .sub a:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.sub-menu .sub:first-child a:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
 text-decoration: underline;
 border-top: 0px solid #000;
}


.links > .no-sub:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navig">
    <div class="links">
        <li class="no-sub">
            <a href="/">Первая категория</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="sub"><a href="/">1Первая ссылка</a></li>
                    <li class="sub"><a href="/">1Вторая ссылка</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="no-sub">
            <a href="/">Вторая категория</a>
        </li>
        <li class="no-sub">
            <a href="/">Категория с подкатегориями</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="sub"><a href="/">Первая ссылка</a></li>
                    <li class="sub"><a href="/">Вторая ссылка</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="no-sub">
            <a href="/">Вторая категория</a>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```